# Liferay 7, Jboss 7 Configuration

Tags: jboss7.x, liferay-7

Can any one please help me configuring Jboss 7 for Liferay 7 in eclipse mars, JDK 8. I tried but it is displaying below lines and stopped.

```
15:46:53,586 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
15:46:53,857 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
15:46:53,895 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

Answer (score 1):

Detailed steps to setup liferay 7 development environment with Tomcat @ http://tirthalpatel.blogspot.in/2016/09/liferay-portal-7-getting-started-guide-series.html

I didn't try with JBoss. But, similar steps should work for JBoss.